# How to apply the ! (not) operator in simple terminal commands

Tags: bash, shell-script, wildcards

It seems to be a really simple thing to do. I have done it in my Bash scripts, but I wonder how to do the same in the terminal.

For example, suppose I want to `ls` all files that are not `js`. Probably I would do:

```
ls ! *.js
```

But I get errors for my `!` operator.

How can I execute `mv`, `rm`, and any other operations with the not (`!`) operator?

**Note that my shell is Bash.**

Comment: Can you show a snip of the bash scripts?

Comment: What errors do you get (please respond by [editing your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/577897/edit), not here in comments)? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the `bash` shell, you should enable `extglob` and run `ls  !(*.js)`.

Example:

```
$ touch file.js file.txt
$ shopt -s extglob
$ ls  !(*.js)
file.txt
```

Comment: does running `shopt -s extglob` enable `extglob` permanently on my terminal, or I have to run it each time?

Comment: It only enables it in the current subshell. You need to add it to your `~/.bashrc` if you want to set it permanently.